# CSS grid - Make column width consistent for repeating rows regardless of content width

Tags: css, css-grid

I have the following css grid that does not keep same width for repeating rows. the data in each cell could have varying length. How to keep the width the same for all repeating rows ?

I want column 1 to be 10% width, Column 2 to be 45% and remaining for column 3. This is why I use:

```
grid-template-areas:
'user-l user-m user-m user-m user-m user-m user-m user-r user-r user-r user-r'
```

The data  `user-container` is repeated for "n" number of users.

```css
body {margin: 0}

.user-l {grid-area:user-l}
.user-m {grid-area:user-m}
.user-r {grid-area:user-r}

.user-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
  'user-l user-m user-m user-m user-m user-m user-m user-r user-r user-r user-r'
}

.user-l,
.user-m,
.user-r {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}

.user-l {background-color: #2196F3}
.user-m {background-color: #219683}
.user-r {background-color: #216683}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements - How to keep width the same ?</h1>

<p>In the example below, blue and green should have the same width all the time. </p>

<div class="user-container">
  <div class="user-l">
   <p>Name: jsdsdsd djsds</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-m">
     <p>Age: 23</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-r">
   <p>Occupation: Doctor</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="user-container">
  <div class="user-l">
   <p>Name: ANother longer Names</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-m">
     <p>Age: 23</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-r">
   <p>Occupation: Another Occupation</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove grid-template-area / grid-area's and add grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);

Comment: @VXp That would make 3 equal width columns right ? I want column 1 to be 10% width, Column 2 to be 45% and remaining for column 3.

Comment: Yes, then add: grid-template-columns: 10% 45% 1fr;

Comment: @VXp If I remove grid-areas, how can I control responsive behaviour. For tablets I want it one below other so will it be `grid-template-columns: 100% 100% 1fr;` to show columns one below other?

Comment: You don't need any of that, grid-template-columns: 1fr; will make it 1 column, simple as that, at particular screen width with @media queries ofc.

Comment: @VXp Ok makes sense. I think this is an answer.

Comment: Most likely it is.

Answer (score 1):

created and fixed the width for `user-l user-m user-r` and added `grid-template-columns: 10% 45% 1fr;` which will provide the size of the div

```css
body {margin: 0}

.user-l {grid-area:user-l}
.user-m {grid-area:user-m}
.user-r {grid-area:user-r}

.user-container {
  display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 10% 45% 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  'user-l user-m  user-r'
  
}

.user-l,
.user-m,
.user-r {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 20px;
}

.user-l {background-color: #2196F3; }
.user-m {background-color: #219683;}
.user-r {background-color: #216683;}
```

```html
<h1>Grid Elements - How to keep width the same ?</h1>

<p>In the example below, blue and green should have the same width all the time. </p>

<div class="user-container">
  <div class="user-l">
   <p>Name: jsdsdsd djsds</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-m">
     <p>Age: 23</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-r">
   <p>Occupation: Doctor</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="user-container">
  <div class="user-l">
   <p>Name: ANother longer Names</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-m">
     <p>Age: 23</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-r">
   <p>Occupation: Another Occupation</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code below should fix the issue. Answer is based on comments above from VXp

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.user-container { display: grid;}
.user-container  {
 grid-template-columns: 10% 45% 1fr; 
  }
  
.user-l {
background-color: #2196F3;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding 20px;
}
.user-m {
background-color: #219683;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding 20px;
}
.user-r {
background-color: #216683;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
padding 20px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Grid Elements - How to keep width the same ?</h1>

<p>In the example below, blue and green should have the same width all the time. </p>


<div class="user-container">
  <div class="user-l">
   <p>Name: jsdsdsd djsds</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-m">
     <p>Age: 23</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-r">
   <p>Occupation: Doctor</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="user-container">
  <div class="user-l">
   <p>Name: ANother longer Names</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-m">
     <p>Age: 23</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-r">
   <p>Occupation: Another Occupation</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```